# Gradient Not Filling Entire Area

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how I can adjust the css in my register.php page so that the gradient will fill the entire area like it does on my login page.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/register

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "make the gradient image a bit taller".

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 gradients.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ will generate cross-browser CSS that works in "all browsers".

Comment: It was a gradient that came with a template and I don't mess with images.I wouldn't know how to handle that link you gave me.

Comment: So you want to do it without changing images or changing CSS? What *can* you change? Nevermind.. I fixed the image (`/kowmanager/assets/images/login.jpg`) for you: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MSfIi.jpg. I kept it exactly the same format and stuff just to be on the safe side. I would have changed it to `.png` and reduced the width..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the same background gradient image for both the login & register forms you can modify your CSS rule to position the gradient at the top of the registration box and apply a background color #E7E7E7 so that the bottom of the gradient fades into a solid color.  Like this:

```
.register-style {
  background: #E7E7E7 url("../images/login.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a taller version of the gradient image and use that in your .register-style class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cover just the case you have on register.php, try to add these styles:

```
.register-style {
    background-position: top;
}

.register-inside {
    height: 276px;
}

.register-data {
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px;
}
```

Doing so you'd position the gradient to top, make the block a little smaller so the gradient would fit and make the paddings of the lighter box a little smaller, so it would look better.

Also, if you have control over the register.php `HTML`, add `class="text"` to the inputs: they'd gain the same style the inputs on login page have.